# Uploading audio files to Firebase Cloud Database and then redering it from the Database to React js + Endless loop issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been facing this issue for quite a while now, and it's really chanllenging, I need help. Thanks in advance.

The following code should be a form that adds new documents easily inside the firestore cloud Data Base collection:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import db from '../index';

const AddSongs = () => {
    const [song, setSong] = useState('');
    const [artist, setArtist] = useState('');
    const [src, setSrc] = useState('');


    const inSubmit = (e) =>{

        e.preventDefault();

        let songBase = db.collection('songs');
        let data = {song, artist, src}

        songBase
            .add(data)

    }


    return ( 
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={inSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Add Your Track
                </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the track" value={song} onChange={e => 
                 setSong(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the artist" value={artist} onChange={e => 
                 setArtist(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="file" value={src} onChange={e => setSrc(e.target.value)} />
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="add it" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddSongs;
```

And then, the docs are added to the cloud Database successfully as normal docs with properties/fields which are song, artist and src. 
And this is another code which should then take the current data inside the collection and renders it to a jsx div

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import db from '../index';

const SongList = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    let songbase = db.collection('songs')

    songbase.onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
            setList([...list, {song: doc.song, artist: doc.artist, src: doc.src, id: Math.random(0,1)}])
        })
    })

    const renderedList = list.length ? (list.map(songItem =>{
        return(
            <div key={songItem.id}>
                <span>{songItem.song}</span>
                <audio controls>
                    <source src={songItem.src} type="audio/mpeg" />
                </audio>
                <span>{songItem.artist}</span>
            </div>
        )
    })) : (<h1>nope !</h1>)


    return ( 
        <div>
            {renderedList}
        </div>
     );
}

export default SongList;
```

And then, what happens here is that the songItem gets rendered inside an empty jsx div containging an empty audio tag inside, and repeats itself endlessly and keeps scrolling down.. ! + the src field in the db which should be rendered in the audio tag is just a string, not a reference for a real file.

I just need to know in this case, how to add any kind of files to the firebase storage, and then reference these files in the Database, and then render the files inside a normal none-repeating div.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You update state on each render, adding new element to array. Of course it leads to endless loop. You need to utilize [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) for fetching data. And instead of calling setList in forEach, call it like this: `setList(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({/*...*/})))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're updating your state every time you add a new element to your list.

Correct code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import db from '../index';

const SongList = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const songbase = db.collection('songs');

    songbase.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      const songList = [];

      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        const newSong = {
          song: doc.song,
          artist: doc.artist,
          src: doc.src,
          id: Math.random(0, 1)
        };

        songList.push(newSong);
      });

      setList(songList);
    });
  }, []);

  const renderedList = list.length ? (
    list.map(songItem => {
      return (
        <div key={songItem.id}>
          <span>{songItem.song}</span>
          <audio controls>
            <source src={songItem.src} type="audio/mpeg" />
          </audio>
          <span>{songItem.artist}</span>
        </div>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <h1>nope !</h1>
  );

  return <div>{renderedList}</div>;
};

export default SongList;
```

One thing to note: there's no need to spread the list in the new array because it will be always [], the default state for list is set to [].

We use the useEffect hook with no dependencies (empty array as a second argument), this will execute the code inside the hook the first time the component renders and the subsequents renders it will not re run the code. This will prevent the infinite loop you where having.

Let me know if you have any doubt!

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks a lot, it worked and I understood. it would be great if you also had any idea on how to upload real files to the cloud storage, and then reference them in the database document fields being rendered, which are song, artist, and src, because currently src is just a string of the fakepath of the song in my computer, I wanted to be a real file so that audio can be played after uploading.
I've also tried to use several storageRef functions from the firebase documentation but it didn't work, or maybe I didn't understand how to use them in this case here. it was a bit challenging.

Comment: I done this for a past project at work. You should use cloud functions and in react you will use form data to upload the files to the server. (You will upload your files to a cloud bucket and then you can modify the document with the link to that data!). Here some links: [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ1EFnFOGvEhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ1EFnFOGvE). There he makes a custom endpoint to upload data to the storage.

Comment: Also, can mark my answer as the correct one? I would appreciate it!!